# jquery variable vs $(jquery varibale), what is difference b/w the two

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do:

```
var x = $("#listing")
```

I get back html element with id `listing`,

And when I do `$(x)` or `$($("#listing"))`, I get the same.

What is difference b/w two?

Comment: `$(...)` converts the object to a **jQuery object/collection**. When doing `$(x)` you are simply creating a new jQuery object from `x`, which is already a jQuery object itself--it is redundant and serves no purpose. However, there is no difference between `$var` and `var`, that is just a naming convention most developer use to distinguish between jQuery objects and native JS objects/variables.

Comment: It's just that JQuery recreate the selector based on the element you gave him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$()` will convert something to a [**jQuery object**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) (or collection). This is not the same as a Javascript variable.

When you store `#listing` in a variable such as `var x = '#listing'`, you are simply passing a string to the jQuery constructor, which is then interpreted as a selector by [Sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/), jQuery's selector engine.

In the example provided, there is no difference between the two following lines:

```
var x = $('#listing');

var x = '#listing',
    $x = $(x);
```

In the first snippet, `x` is identical to `$x` in the second.

In the interest of completeness, the jQuery constructor can also accept a mixed type variable as its first parameter; it doesn't have to be a string. For example, it's possible to convert a `DOMElement` variable into a jQuery object using the following syntax:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('myItem'),
    $ele = $(ele);
```

Notice that `$ele` now has access to jQuery's own functions, such as `addClass()`, etc. Please see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hfwL20fy/).

---

Furthermore, passing a jQuery object to the constructor will simply return the same jQuery object. For example, given the following snippet:

```
var $x  = $('#listing'),
    $x2 = $( $x );
```

`$x` is identical to `$x2`.

Comment: What if we put $(x) here, i mean wrapper jquery element with $, i know it makes no sense, but just curious, what would happen?

Comment: @sahil Console log it and check what you see. Sometimes it's easier to understand things when you do it yourself.

Comment: @sahil Do you mean `$( $x )`? `$(x)` will produce the same as `$('#listing')` as explained.

Comment: When i do same in console, just the order gets swapped i.e.[ul#listing2.LLko, selector: "#listing2", context: document] VS [ul#listing2.LLko, context: document, selector: "#listing2"]

Answer (score 0):

Your x variable was made a jQuery object once it found the dorm item.

Once you run var x = $('#listing'); x has everything wrapping it has.

Thus you can run x.addClass('thing')

Comment: This is not entirely true. The `x` variable is not *made* into a jQuery object, but rather used to construct a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Adding $ is creating jQuery object, its not normal variable. You can create jQuery object from DOM element, from another jQuery object or from normal javascript variable. Try to run `console.log(x)` `console.log($(x))` and it will tell you all differences.